# Kendo Heirarchical Grid Alignment Issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have implemented two **Kendo** Grids, first one is the parent Grid and other is the child Grid.
When I open the Child Grid to view the values for each parent element in the Parent Grid,
the column alignment of both the Grids are mismatched.

Any help on how to solve this ?

Here is the general code :-

// This is the Parent Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<XYZ.Models.ViewModels.ABCMODEL>()
   .Name("ParentGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.A).Title("ABC").Width(30);
        columns.Bound(e => e.B).Title("EFG").Width(30).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "background-color:#996666;" });
        columns.Bound(e => e.C).Title("IJK").Width(30).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "background-color:#996666;" });
        columns.Bound(e => e.D).Title("MNO").Width(30).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "background-color:#996666;" });
        columns.Bound(e => e.E).Title("XYZ.").Width(30).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "background-color:#996666;" });

    })
    //.Scrollable()
    .DetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100%;  background-color: #fcfedf;" })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "tableMain" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        // .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_ABC", "Profit"))
    )
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
    //.ColumnMenu()
    // .Scrollable()
    //.Sortable()
    //.Pageable()
)
```

//This is the Child Grid

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ABC.Models.ViewModels.ABCMODEL>()
        .Name("grid_#=CId#")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.a).Title("123").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.b).Title("456").Format("{0:N3}").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.c).Title("789").Format("{0:N3}").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.d).Title("101").Format("{0:N3}").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.e).Title("112").Format("{0:N3}").Width(30);
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            // .PageSize(5)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_XYZ", "Profit", new { CId =      "#=CId#" }))
        )
        .ToTemplate()
)



</script>


<script>

    function dataBound() {
        var grid = this;


        $(".k-hierarchy-cell").css({ width: 8 });     
       $(".k-hierarchy-col").css({ width: 8 });
    }
</script>


    <style>

.k-grid tbody .k-grid .k-grid-header
{
    display: none;
}    

#ParentGrid .k-grid-header .k-header
{
       background-color: #d42e12;       
       color:White;
       font-size:small; 
       font-style:normal; 
       border:1px; border-color:Black; border-style:solid; text-align:center;
       white-space:nowrap;
}

.k-grid tbody
{
    background-color: #fcfedf; 
    height:100%; 
    font-size:x-small;
    border:none;
    border-color: #fcfedf; 
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#ParentGrid .k-grid td
{
  border:none   
  padding-right: 0em !important;

}

</style>
```

Hope now the question becomes more clear.
Looking forward to a useful answer.

Comment: I think you may be able to post very general code that doesn't give away any business logic or "secrets". But you would know better than me.

Comment: Added the general code,any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answers and comments.
They helped me a lot in reaching to an answer to my question.

So here is the final solution :

// This is the Parent Grid (No need to do any changes in Parent Grid,it remains as it is
with width attribute in every column)

//This is the Child Grid (All changes are to be done in "Child Grid")

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ABC.Models.ViewModels.ABCMODEL>()
        .Name("grid_#=CId#")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.a).Title("123");
            columns.Bound(e => e.b).Title("456").Format("{0:N3}").Width(149);
            columns.Bound(e => e.c).Title("789").Format("{0:N3}").Width(150);
            columns.Bound(e => e.d).Title("101").Format("{0:N3}").Width(137);
            columns.Bound(e => e.e).Title("112").Format("{0:N3}").Width(127);
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            // .PageSize(5)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_XYZ", "Profit", new { CId =      "#=CId#" }))
        )
        .ToTemplate()
)
```

You have to remove the width from the "first column in the child grid i.e. column "a"" and start setting the width from the last column.

Give a width to the last column of child grid such that it gets aligned with the last column of "parent grid" i.e.
Align column "e of child grid" with "E of parent grid" by giving "e" a suitable value.

Once "e" is aligned,it will be fixed,now in the similar way align column "d,b,c" and you will find column "a" aligned with "A in parent grid".

In this way both the grids get aligned.

The values in the width attribute were specific to my screen so i used them.These are not standard values.Try and align the child grid according to your screen,the values might be different.

Hope it helps,thanks a lot and have a great New Year ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Had to get a little fancy with some css, but here is a sample of where I had to accomplish this.

http://jsbin.com/uritAno/2/edit

I think the main thing was to override the right padding and border on the grid td's, and set each column to a fixed width, save for one.

```
.k-grid td
{
  border: none;
  padding-right: 0em !important;
}
```

Comment: I can't add the "border:none" option as it would remove the borders, and paading:right : 0em !important didn't help much. 
You can review my code,you will get a better idea for sure.

Comment: Try removing the width from the Title column on both parent and child grids, but leave it on the rest of the columns.

Comment: Hi @giltnerj0, thanks a lot for your comment.                            
Actually the title column we have added in all the columns in the parent and the child Grids.So could you please elaborate your solution.

Comment: Sorry, not the title column, but one of the columns (take e.a column as a test), and drop the Width(30) on that column.

Comment: The problem is that the width of columns of the parent grid is fixed but the width of child grid columns is dynamic even though i have applied .Width(30) in the code.The width in the child grid columns increases/decreases depending upon the value from DB.

Comment: The link you posted http://jsbin.com/uritAno/2/edit itself has the same alignment issue.The alignment is mismatched.Is it supposed to be like that always?

Comment: It indents on the left, but aligns all the columns save for the title.  I'm not sure it is possible if you are trying to precisely align a child to the parent grid on every column.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your comments.They helped me a lot to reach the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Kendo UI Javascript Grid and inspired by Robin Giltner answer, I resolve by:

1) Using same the width on **paired** columns which have to be aligned on the right. (Starting from the right)

2) Leaving free width on dynamic width columns. (Starting from the left)

3) Overriding `.k-detail-cell` class as follows:

```
    .k-detail-cell
    {
        padding-right: 0em !important;
    }
```

Applying `padding-right: 0em !important;` to `.k-detail-cell` we align only the details grid to the right; while applying `padding-right: 0em !important;` to `.k-grid td` we align to the right, all the columns of both grids and their content. 
(Not nice, because even header and footer are aligned to the right)

*Note: Kendo UI version 2014.2.716*